# Java Hibernate ElementCollection of nested lists

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm looking to have hibernate create mapping tables of lists of lists ie.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@OrderBy("id")
private List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates
```

is there a way to use tags to map this triple nested list?